# paintComponent is not working at all

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I'm using paintComponent to make a GUI for a class assignment and it's just not affecting the appearance of the GUI at all. To start, I'm just setting the background to white. The following code works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PA05a extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("MouseDrawDemo");
    JPanel content = new JPanel();

    content.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocation(120,70);
    window.setSize(400,300);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

but this does not:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PA05a extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("MouseDrawDemo");
    JPanel content = new JPanel();

    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocation(120,70);
    window.setSize(400,300);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //add backdrop
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
  }
}
```

I can't just not use paintComponent because I'll later be adding things that will change from frame to frame. Can someone pinpoint where I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel content = new PA05a();
```

You did not create an object of PA05a. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to create your object. Change your code to:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PA05a extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("MouseDrawDemo");
    JPanel content = new PA05a();

    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocation(120,70);
    window.setSize(400,300);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //add backdrop
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
  }
}
```